# noob qn about on update cascade

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

If I have two tables tableinfo and tablenamelist and a foreign key like so:

```
Alter tableinfo add foreign key (name) references tablenamelist(name) on update cascade;
```

In which situations will the records be modified?

My understanding is that if I change 'bob' to 'Bobby' in tablenamelist it will update all instances of 'bob' to 'Bobby' in tableinfo. 
What happens though if I change a name in the tableinfo table? If I change a record from 'bob' to 'tim' will it change records in tableinfo? Or will it just reassign that record to the new name?

Comment: it wouldn't let me post a question with the word 'question' in the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first assumption is correct, if you change the name in `tablenamelist`, it will change in table `tableinfo`.

Your second assumption is incorrect, you will receive a foreign key violation if you try to change the name in table `tableinfo` to something that does not exist in table `tablenamelist`.

The foreign key is a constraint that enforces the existance of the key in the foreign table.

From [Foreign key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key)

> In the context of relational databases, a foreign key is a referential
>   constraint between two tables.

Also from [14.3.5.4. FOREIGN KEY Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

> InnoDB rejects any INSERT or UPDATE operation that attempts to create
>   a foreign key value in a child table if there is no a matching
>   candidate key value in the parent table.